# How do I convert a host name in to a boost address or endpoint?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using a C++ Redis Library on top of Boost. (https://github.com/nekipelov/redisclient)

To connect, I have to give it either a single tcp endpoint:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint
```

Or an address + port

```
boost::asio::ip::address, unsigned short
```

Currently, I started with:

```
boost::asio::ip::address address = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(someIPVariable);
```

and passed that along with the port, it worked fine and connected. However, I now need to do it by hostname instead of IP. If I simply put the host name in to the line above, it throws an exception as I think it expects an IP address.

I'm used to specifying connections as just `("IP OR Hostname", port)` so I'm a little unsure what's required here. I checked the constructors for both to see if any could convert a host name + port to what was required, but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use a `tcp::resolver` to do name resolution (i.e. DNS lookup):

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("example.com", "80");
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iter = resolver.resolve(query);
```

Dereferencing the iterator gives you a resolver entry that has a `tcp::endpoint`:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = iter->endpoint();
```

Comment: Note that there might be more matches and the lookup can be done asynchronously (important if your IO is async to begin with)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go and accept if all good. We're using this synchronously at the moment. @sehe If there are multiple matches, what should be done? There should only be one (LAN environment, with host files to point machine name to IP), but can never be too careful.

Comment: It returns an iterator to a sequence of one or more matches, so if there is more than one then you iterate over them. If the `resolve` call is successful (i.e. doesn't throw, or doesn't set the `error_condition` for the non-throwing overload) then there is guaranteed to be at least one result, but maybe more.

Comment: @mGuv you select the one that is preferred and/or the one that is working (e.g. IPV4 vs. IPV6)

Comment: Right, only just got around to testing all this. It's working. Thank you very much,

Comment: They do make this overly complicated. Why do I need a port to get the ip address and what is the io_service? I just have a host name and port and want to create a socket.

Comment: How do you "iterate" over anything? A method returns an iterator but where is the "end" that you need to check it against?

Comment: @CashCow [RTFM](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver_iterator/basic_resolver_iterator.html)? Or the [tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html#boost_asio.tutorial.tutdaytime1)? A default constructed iterator is the end, just like `istream_iterator` and friends. You need a port because the result is an endpoint suitable for opening a socket, and an TCP endpoint includes a port. And if you have a port what's the problem?

Comment: I did and the obvious difference between this and standard POSIX / Winsock interfaces is that you create the socket in one go, you don't first resolve the host then create the socket afterwards. However my first attempt on the client side was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Old thread but for anyone interested...

**Asynchronous version:**

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::io_service::strand io_strand(io_service);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);

resolver.async_resolve({"host", "port"}, 
  io_strand.wrap([this](const boost::system::error_code& ec, 
                        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
{
    if (!ec)
    {
        std::for_each(endpoint_iterator, {}, [this](auto& it)
        {
            std::cout << it.endpoint().address() << std::endl;
        });
    }
    else
    {
        //ec.message()?
    }
}));
```

*Note(1):* we can have multiple results from the resolve function due to systems having multiple network interfaces/adapters. This is why we should iterate through the results and check "whatever" suits your needs. E.g. check if `endpoint.address().is_v4();`.

*Note(2):* don't forget to run the I/O service: `io_service.run();`.